# Store string of array from json response in realm

Tags: java, android, realm, retrofit2

This is my JSON response which I need to store in realm.

```
{
  "account": {
    "_id": "xx123",
    "user_id": "abc999",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "email": "random12@gmail.com",
        "email_platform": [
          "email"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As we can not store `List<String>` I have created a custom class for string value using [this example](https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/1a97377df0c49cd4fca9#file-example-json) but it gives me following error

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 199 path $.data.account.accounts[0].email_platform[0]:`

```
public class StringClassEmail  extends RealmObject{
    private String emailVal;

    public StringClassEmail() {
    }

    public StringClassEmail(String emailVal) {
        this.emailVal = emailVal;
   }
```

}

here is also accounst class if required

```
public class UserAccountList extends RealmObject {
   @SerializedName("email")
   @Expose
   private String email;

    @SerializedName("email_platform")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<StringClassEmail> emailPlatform;


   //getter and setter
```

}

Comment: show full exception stacktrace, and show on which line in code the exception happens.

Comment: no, add it to the question please

Comment: ok, I see. The problem is that your `email_platform` is array of strings, and you are trying to deserialize it as an array of objects

Comment: @VladMatvienko how do I do it correctly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with RealmDB enough, but try using `RealmList<String> emailPlatform;` instead of your realmlist.

Comment: @VladMatvienko it doesn't support primitive data type

Comment: then use just a `List<String>` instead.

Comment: @VladMatvienko it had to be realmList

Comment: ok, there is such a nice thing as *google*, which gave me an answer in something like 14 seconds: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=RealmObject+with+list+of+strings&oq=RealmObject+with+list+of+strings&aqs=chrome..69i57.4664j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should generate your DTOs with jsonschema2pojo

```
    -----------------------------------com.example.Account.java-----------------------------------

            package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class AccountDTO {

        @SerializedName("_id")
        @Expose
        private String id;
        @SerializedName("user_id")
        @Expose
        private String userId;
        @SerializedName("accounts")
        @Expose
        private List<EmailDTO> emails = null;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(String userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public List<EmailDTO> getEmails() {
            return emails;
        }

        public void setAccounts(List<EmailDTO> emails) {
            this.emails = emails;
        }
    }

-----------------------------------com.example.Account_.java-----------------------------------

            package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class EmailDTO {

        @SerializedName("email")
        @Expose
        private String email;
        @SerializedName("email_platform")
        @Expose
        private List<String> emailPlatform = null;

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public List<String> getEmailPlatform() {
            return emailPlatform;
        }

        public void setEmailPlatform(List<String> emailPlatform) {
            this.emailPlatform = emailPlatform;
        }

    }
-----------------------------------com.example.Response.java-----------------------------------

            package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Response {
        @SerializedName("account")
        @Expose
        private AccountDTO account;

        public AccountDTO getAccount() {
            return account;
        }

        public void setAccount(AccountDTO account) {
            this.account = account;
        }
    }
```

---

---

Then define RealmObject classes as well

```
public class Account extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    @Index
    private String userId;

    private User user;

    private RealmList<Email> emails = null;
}

public class Email extends RealmObject {
   @Index
   private String email;

   private RealmList<EmailPlatform> emailPlatform;
}

public class EmailPlatform extends RealmObject {
    @Index
    private String platform;

    private Email email;
}
```

And then parse the JSON with GSON, then map it over to Realm's schema, then insert it to db.